# How do I obtain all the flash variables from a ShockwaveFlashObject? (C++)

Tags: c++, flash, variables

Is it possible to retrieve all the variables in a swf url in C++?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a debugger, that can inspect the code at runtime, look up stack frames and the variables they contain. It is written in Java, however, it is open source, so, nothing stops you from porting it to C++. That would be quite a task though...

The sources are here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/flex/trunk/modules/debugger/